# Is any subchain of Markov chain also a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

Suppose $X_i$ is a Markov chain, which is defined by

$$p(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = p(X_1)p(X_1\mid X_2)p(X_2\mid X_3)\ldots p(X_{n-1}\mid X_n)$$

For arbitrary subchain $X_{\alpha_k}$, where $1\le \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \cdots < \alpha_m \le n$, is it a Markov chain?

Comment: Don't you mean $P(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n) = P(X_1)P(X_2 \mid X_1) \cdots P(X_n \mid X_{n-1})$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Markov property can be stated as $X_3$ being conditionally independent of $X_1$ given $X_2$, or $p(X_1,X_3|X_2)=p(X_1|X_2)p(X_3|X_2)$. More generally, you can apply this property multiple times to get, for some $m$,

$$
 p(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{m-1},X_{m+1},\dots,X_n|X_m)=p(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{m-1}|X_m)p(X_{m+1},\dots,X_n|X_m).
$$

Now take $1\le \alpha <\beta<\gamma\le n$. Using above property you can write

$$
p(X_\alpha,X_\gamma|X_\beta) 
= \sum_{X_i:i\in\{\alpha+1,\dots,\beta-1,\beta+1,\dots\gamma-1\}} p(X_\alpha,X_{\alpha+1},\dots,X_{\beta-1},X_{\beta+1},\dots,X_\gamma|X_\beta)\\
= \sum_{X_i:i\in\{\alpha+1,\dots,\beta-1,\beta+1,\dots\gamma-1\}}
p(X_\alpha,X_{\alpha+1},\dots,X_{\beta-1}|X_\beta)p(X_{\beta+1},\dots,X_\gamma|X_\beta)\\
= \sum_{X_i:i\in\{\alpha+1,\dots,\beta-1\}}\sum_{X_j:j\in\{\beta+1,\dots\gamma-1\}}
p(X_\alpha,X_{\alpha+1},\dots,X_{\beta-1}|X_\beta)p(X_{\beta+1},\dots,X_\gamma|X_\beta)\\
= \left(\sum_{X_i:i\in\{\alpha+1,\dots,\beta-1\}}
p(X_\alpha,X_{\alpha+1},\dots,X_{\beta-1}|X_\beta)\right)\left(\sum_{X_j:j\in\{\beta+1,\dots\gamma-1\}}p(X_{\beta+1},\dots,X_\gamma|X_\beta)\right)\\
=p(X_\alpha|X_\beta)p(X_\gamma|X_\beta)
$$